# Folder won't push to Github

Tags: github

I'm following along "Rebuilding Rails" and I'm trying to push the rulers/ folder to github but I can't seem to add the folder? I have a repo setup and can push some files but not the rulers/ folder.

I've tried

```
git add .
git add *
git add ruler
```

I've tried pulling, merging, and a few other.

my .gitignore contains:

```
/.bundle/
/.yardoc
/_yardoc/
/coverage/
/doc/
/pkg/
/spec/reports/
/tmp/
```

If I cd into the folder I get:

```
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:*******/railZ.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.


On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   rulers (untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Is the folder empty or do you have files in there?

Comment: I have files in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't commit empty folders in Git. If you want this folder to exist in the repo, you have to put a file in it.

By convention, you could use an empty file named `.gitkeep`, but any file will do.

Comment: It's not an empty folder.

Comment: @ZackWilliams The answer is in the error message you just added: It's nothing to do with the new folder, there's just another commit on the branch you're pushing to. Perhaps you amended a commit and are now trying to push the new one?

Comment: I tried pulling and it says "already up to date"

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to put .gitkeep in the folder with the other files and it still pushes nothing

Comment: How can I fix this? I've tried the hints.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the rules folder is:

- a nested Git repository (there would be a `rulers/.git` subfolder)
- a submodule (the parent repository would have a .gitmodules listing it)

I mention that possibility, because of repositories like [`noahgibbs/rulers`](https://github.com/noahgibbs/rulers), which represent the `rulers` folder/repository.

In both cases, pushing the parent repository would result in an "empty" rulers folder (actually a placeholder, for another repository)

Comment: I don't see a ruler/.git subfolder there is a rulers/version.rb though.

Any suggestions on how to fix this so I can push it to my repo?

Comment: Do you see a .gitmodules anywhere above the rulers folder?

Comment: No, there isn't a .gitmodules either.‍♂️